# Apostrophe in Email Address throwing Exception

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have to send email to users using JavaMail API.

User may have email address with apostrophe some like

```
 Michael.O’Hara@sampleDomain.com
```

I am getting below exception when I try to send an email to such a user.

```
    javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1564)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1551)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.close(SMTPTransport.java:696)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:191)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
    at com.openpages.ext.duke.util.DukeEmailUtil.sendNotification(DukeEmailUtil.java:194)
```

Following is the method that I am using to send email

```
public static void sendNotification(String mailServer, String fromName,
            String fromAddress, String toAddress, String ccAddresses,
            String subject, String emailContent) throws Exception {
        try {

            // TODO: The email session should be cached in a future release.
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", mailServer);

            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            InternetAddress addressFrom = null;
            if (StringUtil.isGood(fromName))
                addressFrom = new InternetAddress(fromAddress, fromName);
            else
                addressFrom = new InternetAddress(fromAddress);
            msg.setFrom(addressFrom);

            if (toAddress != null && !toAddress.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                String[] toAddressesArray = toAddress.split(";");
                InternetAddress[] addressTO = new InternetAddress[toAddressesArray.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < toAddressesArray.length; i++) {
                    LoggerFactory.getLogger().error("Before InternetAdress Contructor");
                    addressTO[i] = new InternetAddress(toAddressesArray[i]);
                    LoggerFactory.getLogger().error("After InternetAdress Contructor");

                }
                msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTO);
            }

            // TODO : method signature has to be changed
            // to take String[] for toAddress & ccAddresses
            if (ccAddresses != null && !ccAddresses.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                String[] ccAddressesArray = ccAddresses.split(";");
                InternetAddress[] addressCC = new InternetAddress[ccAddressesArray.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < ccAddressesArray.length; i++) {
                    addressCC[i] = new InternetAddress(ccAddressesArray[i]);
                }
                msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, addressCC);
            }

            msg.setSubject(subject, "utf-8");
            msg.setContent(emailContent, "text/html;charset=utf-8");
            Transport.send(msg);

            msg = null;
            session = null;
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

If anyone can tell me how to fix this, that will be great.

Comment: What mail server are you connecting to? Can it handle these characters in the local part of the email address?

Comment: What class and method throws the exception?

Comment: Are you sure you are using ASCII apostrophe (hex 0x27)?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible ways to deal with this (don't know how your code looks exactly, if you can post some code that shows how the messages are sent that would be cool).

- Use strict=false e.g. `new InternetAddress("Michael.O’Hara@sampleDomain.com", false)`
- Alternative to the above, put the email address itself in double quotes, although that's more of a workaround
- Relax the strict validation on the Session object `session.setProperty("mail.mime.address.strict", "false");`

Answer (score 0):

The RFC 2822 spec absolutely requires that the local part of an address that contains special characters such as this be quoted, i.e., "Michael.O’Hara"@sampleDomain.com.

Comment: Even After quoting the email I am getting an error in SMTP Transport class as below   javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1564)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1551)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.close(SMTPTransport.java:696)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:191)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)

Comment: What does the [protocol trace](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?